# using linq to order tickets by lowest date where ticket is not closed?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have an object called Ticket with that contains a list of objects called TicketActions. The Ticket object has a field called Date_Closed and the Actions object has a field called Action_Date:

```
Ticket
   Date_Closed
   TicketActions
      -Action_Date
```

What I'm trying to do is order a List of tickets (List) based on the latest date of each Action in ascending order where the Ticket does not have a value for Date_Closed. The goal is to load this list into a listview and show tickets in a way that displays tickets in order on the page, placing the ones that have gone the longest without an action at the top. Does that make sense?

Here is what I ended up with so far that isn't working:

```
protected List<FullTicket> BuildTickets(int ticketsToShow)
{
    using (var db = new SupportLogDBDataContext())
    {
        var result =
            (from ticket in db.Support_Tickets
            join status in db.Ticket_Statuses on ticket.Status_ID equals status.ID
            select new FullTicket
            {
                TicketID = ticket.ID,
                DateOpened = (DateTime)ticket.Date_Opened,
                DateClosed = (DateTime)ticket.Date_Closed,
                Subject = ticket.Subject,
                Status = new KeyPair { Key = status.Status, Value = status.ID },
                CreatedBy = new GuidPair { Key = ticket.Reported_By, Value = (Guid)ticket.AD_GUID },
                TicketActions =
                    (from a in db.Ticket_Actions
                     where a.Ticket_ID == ticket.ID
                     select a).ToList()
            }).Take(ticketsToShow).ToList();
        result.OrderBy(i => i.TicketActions.Where(i.DateClosed == null).Max()); //error on this line (invalid arguments)
        return result;
    }        
}
```

Comment: simple mistake in question and likely your problem. `result = result.OrderBy...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David B's analysis is slightly off.  The line...

```
result.OrderBy(i => i.TicketActions.Where(i.DateClosed == null).Max());
```

... will not compile because the argument to the `Where` method is not a lambda expression or delegate.

I would suggest this solution (assuming that the relevant property of the TicketAction type is `ActionDate`):

```
return result.Where(i => i.DateClosed == null)
  .OrderBy(i => i.TicketActions.Max(a => a.ActionDate));
```

Or, in query comprehension syntax:

```
return from i in result
    where i.DateClosed == null
    orderby i.TicketActions.Max(a => a.ActionDate)
    select i;
```

Answer (score 2):

People reply quick here!

Try this:

```
var result = (from ticket in tickets
              where !ticket.DateClosed.HasValue
              select ticket).OrderByDescending(t => (from a in t.TicketActions
                                                     select a.ActionDate).Max());
```

From here you can take as many as you need.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some simple code.

```
var sorted = tickets.Where(t => t.DateClosed == null)
                    .OrderBy(t => t.TicketActions.Max(ta => ta.Action_Date.Ticks));
```

Sorry, I prefer LINQ function syntax, but if you want it in query syntax, it shouldn't be too hard to convert.

Answer (score 1):

```
result.OrderBy(i => i.TicketActions.Where(i.DateClosed == null).Max());
```

This line generates an error because TicketActions.Max() is not defined.
You need to project TicketAction into something that can be Max'd.  For example:

```
result.OrderBy(i =>
  i.TicketActions
  .Where(ta => i.DateClosed == null)
  .Select(ta => ta.Id)
  .Max()
);
```

Also note:

1. OrderBy does not modify its source.  OrderBy **returns** an ordered IEnumerable, which you didn't assign anywhere.
2. OrderBy's enumerable is deferred, and you want a List result instead, so you should call ToList.
3. You are accessing Ticket.TicketActions outside of the query.  This will cause one database round trip *per ticket* to load that property.

---

Here is a modification to your query that avoids the problems mentioned above by ordering and using navigational properties **within the query**.

```
from ticket in db.Support_Tickets
where ticket.DateClosed == null
let lastDate = ticket.TicketActions
  .Select(ta => ta.ActionDate)
  .OrderByDescending(date => date)
  .FirstOrDefault()
let ticketStatus = ticket.TicketStatus
order by lastDate
select new FullTicket
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: TicketActions is a list, which can indeed be `Max`ed.  The problem is the argument to `Where`.  Also, your `lastDate` variable will actually hold the latest action itself, not the date of the latest action.

Comment: @phoog how can you max something that is not comparable?

Comment: By passing a lambda to extract a numeric value from each element.

Comment: @phoog if you do that, you are Max'ing a comparable thing. Question asker wasn't doing that.  Can we agree that there are so many problems with the original code that it is hard to communicate all the needed repair information easily?

Comment: True, he wasn't doing it, but he wanted to do it: "order a List of tickets *based on the latest date of each Action* in ascending order" (emphasis added).  I agree there are lots of problems with the original code, but the prose description of the problem was clear enough.

Comment: It is my position that my answer helpfully addresses the many problems in that code, and this discussion adds nothing.

Comment: The answer does address many problems of the code, but it misdiagnoses the "invalid arguments" compilation error.  I disagree that pointing out the misdiagnosis "adds nothing".